# How to only upload specific parts of HTML form with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a html form with 4 inputs but 1 of the inputs is connected to a mysql table usersettings and the other 3 inputs are connected to the table userinfo, the 4 inputs are all update queries, none of the fields are required to be filled in. Here is the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="settingsFirst">
        <div id="sfInner">
            <div id="soDelete1">
                &nbsp;Selecteer voor hoe lang uw taken actief blijven:
            </div>
                <div id="soDelete2">
                    <select id="selectDelete" name="deleteValue">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteer:</option>
                        <option value="1">1 uur</option>
                        <option value="2">12 uur</option>
                        <option value="3">1 dag</option>
                        <option value="4">Elke week</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="settingsSecond">
            <div id="wwChange1">
                &nbsp;Wachtwoord veranderen:
            </div>
            <div id="wwChange2">
                &nbsp;Oud wachtwoord: <input id="wwChanger1" name="oldWW" type="password"></input><br>
                &nbsp;Nieuw wachtwoord: <input id="wwChanger2" name="newWW1" type="password"></input><br>
                &nbsp;Herhaal wachtwoord: <input id="wwChanger3" name="newWW2" type="password"></input>
            </div>
            <div id="wwChange3">
                <input id="saveSettings" name="submit" type="submit" value="Opslaan"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the PHP upload script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(isset($_POST['deleteValue'])){
            if($q8 = $db->prepare("UPDATE usersettings SET deletetimer = " . $deletetimer . " WHERE studid = '" . $studid . "'")){
                $q8->execute();
            }
        }
        if(isset($_POST['wwChanger1']) && isset($newWachtwoord) && isset($newWachtwoordHH)){
            if($_POST['wwChanger1'] == $wachtwoord && $newWachtwoord == $newWachtwoordHH){
                if($q9 = $db->prepare("UPDATE userinfo SET wachtwoord = '" . $newWachtwoord . "' WHERE studid = '" . $studid . "'")){
                    $q9->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I am trying to only upload the relevant part of the form which is filled in so if the `select` is filled in it should update usersettings table, if the password change is filled in it should update userinfo table and if everything is filled in both tables should update. But for some reason when I try to call for a password change it won't update my table and my old password is still in there. I don't get any errors either. What's wrong?

Comment: have you debugged/dumped out the values of `$_POST['wwChanger1']`, `$wachtwoord`, `$newWachtwoord` and `$newWachtwoordHH`?

Comment: Should I just dump all variables after the update and then set the session variable for my regular password to the inputted password?

Comment: Is it actually necessary that you have to dump them?

Comment: He didn't mean dump as in delete, he meant it as printing out their values so you can see their type and content.

Comment: I know that but I know there the right value types but ill check it anyway

Comment: It isn't setting the variables if I use the syntax right before the if is called it returns NULL string(5) NULL NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verification should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['oldWW']) && isset($newWachtwoord) && isset($newWachtwoordHH)){
            if($_POST['oldWW'] == $wachtwoord && $newWachtwoord == $newWachtwoordHH){
                if($q9 = $db->prepare("UPDATE userinfo SET wachtwoord = '" . $newWachtwoord . "' WHERE studid = '" . $studid . "'")){
                    $q9->execute();
                }
            }
        }
```

Assuming your other variables $wachtwoord are set correctly.
You probably should get those by $_POST as well.

Comment: I got this part right oldWW is in my case $wachtwoord which refers to the session password I'm using and $newWachtwoord,$newWachtwoordHH refer to the $_POST versions

Comment: So are you fetching the values from your $_POST ?
$newWachtwoord = $_POST['newWW1']; ?

Comment: Yes I did it like that:$newWachtwoord = $_POST['wwChanger2'];
   $newWachtwoordHH = $_POST['wwChanger3'];

Comment: Oh god i'm just not paying attention. In the $_POST I filled in the id of the inputs not the name

Comment: It's working now. I didn't realize I was using the id values instead of the name value, thanks for the help, your comment from $newWachtwoord = $_POST['newWW1']; got the problem for me